# WebRTC websocket SSL certs use to work but not any more? ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: ssl, websocket, webrtc, sip, freeswitch

I am using sipml5 to register sip endpoints and using sipml5 as my client and FreeSwitch as my SIP server. I use to be able to register my sip endpoint and establish a connection, but recently I been getting this error in my chrome and Firefox dev console "ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE Error in connection establishment". I looked at probably causes and was not able to solve my problem. When I change my proxy to using ws instead of wss it works.
I am using SHA256 algorithm in my SSL cert.
I added my domain name to SubjectAltName as well as my CN in my SSL cert as well.
I am using openssl to create these certs.

What else could be the cause of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever the websocket server lives (wss://my_ip:7443) needs to have a proper certificate. For now, you can manually accept the certificate by typing https://my_ip:7443 into your browser.

Toye